# Function almost always periodic for every period is constant

Tags: measure-theory, almost-everywhere, measurable-functions

Let be $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ a measure space and $f: X \to [0, +\infty]$ a measurable function such that for every $x \in X$ we have $f(t + x) = f(t)$ for almost every $t \in X$. Is true that $f$ is constant? or constant almost everywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints: as a simple consequence of Fubini's Theorem, for almost all $t$, the equation $f(x+t)=f(t)$ holds for almost all $x$. [Use the fact that $\int \int |f(x+t)-f(t)| dx dt =\int \int |f(x+t)-f(t)| dt dx$ ].  In particular this holds for one value of $t$ and hence $f$ is constant almost everywhere. Can you see that $f$ need not be constant? [Take characteristic function of a non-empty set of measure $0$]. Will be happy to provide a detailed answer if needed.

Comment: Thanks! Really cool and helpful. Only the last step is not clear to me: we need that $\mu$ is translation-invariant to conclude? Because I got $\exists t_0$ such that for almost all x $f(x + t_0) = f(t_0)$ and I want to conclude that $\exists t_0$ such that for almost all x $f(x) = f(t_0)$. Is translation-invariance needed?

Comment: (i.e that if we translate the null set it remains a null set)

Comment: @MarcoAll-inNervo Precisely! I am using translation invariance of Lebesgue measure in the last part.