# Translationally invariant measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure

Consider the following:

> Let $f$ be a Borel measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with Lebesgue measure such that $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$:
> $$
> f(x+a) = f(x)\quad \text{a.e.}
> $$
> Then $f$ is constant a.e.

I've been thinking about this but I can't make any progress. I initially thought it was obvious, but now I'm not even sure that it's true; on the other hand, I know of no counterexample. Can anyone clear this up? In case it isn't true, does it hold at least for some restricted classes of functions, such as integrable ones?

EDIT: After some more thinking, I've realized that any such function which is integrable is $0$ a.e.

Comment: I believe the argument given here should do it: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3064861/522332.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't even occur to me to search for "periodic measurable functions". Unless anyone has any objections, I won't delete this question in case someone else is in the same boat.

Comment: Since Alphie provided appropriate link, I've started a vote to close this as a duplicate.